# Flutter: MultipartRequest returns 403 Forbidden... CURL works fine

Tags: flutter

I try the following **CURL** command:

```
    -X PUT \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
    --upload-file ${file_name} \
    ${url}
```

To upload a file into [Google Storage](https://storage.googleapis.com/...?signature=...&...). This works just fine.

However, when I try to do it using the following **Flutter code** - I get a response with *Error 403 (Forbidden)*:

```
  Future<http.Response?> uploadVideo(
      {required String uploadURL, required filePath}) async {
    try {
      ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(filePath);

      var data =
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes.buffer.asInt64List());
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(uploadURL);

      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'PUT',
        uri,
      );

      request.files.add(data);
      request.headers.addAll({
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
      });

      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
      return await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      showNoInternetError(e);
   }
```

Any idea why this happens? The `uploadURL` is the same as the one I sent through **CURL** (very long string, with signature and ampersand signs etc).

Thanks a lot!!! <3

Comment: I think you you put the key contentTypeHeader twice. Can you try following please: 
`HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/octet-stream',`

Comment: @ruclip Thanks - makes sense - changed but it's still "Forbidden" :-(